# Responsive design - 3-level navigation

Tags: navigation, responsive-design, mega-menu

I'm currently working on a site with a quite complex information architecture. The IA has 3 levels and each level can have up to 12 items.

- Level 1: 4 items
- Level 2: up to 12 items
- Level 3: up to 9 items

On desktop, I'm using a mega dropdown (e.g. [Mashable](http://mashable.com/)) and I need to adapt this for smaller screens and mobiles.
I'm exploring concepts at the moment and have found this example: [Multi-Level Push Menu](http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index3.html#)

How would you solve this problem and what pattern would you use?

Comment: You gave Mashable as an example for the desktop menu. But you can take the mobile version as an example too, it has a simplified menu. Did you take a mobile friendly IA into account? Or is it simply impossible to avoid confronting people on their way with lots of options on a small screen?

Answer (score 1):

Another pattern to consider is a multi-step toggle, as illustrated here: http://codepen.io/bradfrost/full/qwJvF from the excellent [This is Responsive](https://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html) resource. Another interesting idea is to [skip the subnav entirely](http://codepen.io/bradfrost/full/vljdx).

I've been trying to keep tabs on this problem too, so perhaps these will be relevant to you:

- [UX Designers Side Drawer Navigation Costing Half User Engagement](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2014/04/08/ux-designers-side-drawer-navigation-costing-half-user-engagement/)
- [Mobile Menu AB Test](http://exisweb.net/mobile-menu-abtest)
- [Menu Eats Hamburger](http://exisweb.net/menu-eats-hamburger)

Really, whatever you choose should be informed by usability testing/hallway testing/whatever you can afford to do.

A parting thought: "[Obvious always wins.](https://twitter.com/UXHow/status/542680789276979200)"

[image]

Comment: Good last point and although it pretty much is in that case, "Obvious" isn't always as obvious to everyone in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

jazZRo took the words off my keyboard.  I was going to suggest looking at what Mashable do in a responsive view to see what their solution is.

I have recently spotted a clever alternative that Apple (http://www.apple.com/) have done - note you should open this on a mobile device to view it properly - where they still keep all the top level items but you can rotate through them all without having to re-structure the nav.

As an alternative to the high level, the site for the Rugby world cup uses a collapsible sidebar (Microsoft Azure uses this for their navigation where each item opens another item next to it)[image: Microsoft Azure]

I think their argument would fall under the lines of when a user is focusing on the nav, the rest of the page becomes less important.